# How to Edit email alerts Templates from Issue Tracker?

Tags: wss-3.0, list, alert

Hi
I want to edit the email alerts format sent from a Issue Tracker.

I need to know which files I have to edit to customize the email alerts?

I use WSS 3.0

-Saumil

Comment: Saumil, Did you ever find the answer to this question? If yes, could you post it as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you read this first: [Customizing Alert Notifications and Alert Templates in Windows SharePoint Services 3.0](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/sharepointdeveloperdocs/archive/2007/12/07/customizing-alert-notifications-and-alert-templates-in-windows-sharepoint-services-3-0.aspx)

**SPAlertTemplateType.GenericList**
The first alert template in Alerttemplates.xml. GenericList is used unless there is a match to one of other event types.

**SPAlertTemplateType.DocumentLibrary**
 Notification of changes in document libraries

**SPAlertTemplateType.Survey** 
 Notification of changes in surveys

**SPAlertTemplateType.Links**
 Notification of changes in links

**SPAlertTemplateType.Announcements**
 Notification of changes in announcements

**SPAlertTemplateType.Contacts**
 Notification of changes in contacts

**SPAlertTemplateType.Events**
 Notification of changes in events

**SPAlertTemplateType.Tasks**
 Notification of changes in tasks

**SPAlertTemplateType.DiscussionBoard**
 Notification of changes in discussion boards

**SPAlertTemplateType.PictureLibrary**
 Notification of changes in picture libraries

**SPAlertTemplateType.XMLForm**
 Notification of changes in XML form

**SPAlertTemplateType.DataConnectionLibrary**
 Notification of changes in data connection libraries

**SPAlertTemplateType.AssignedtoNotification**
 Assigned to task / issue list notifications